# Does $\nabla g=\omega(\cdot) g$ imply $\nabla$ is metric w.r.t a conformal rescaling of $g$?

Tags: riemannian-geometry, examples-counterexamples, vector-bundles, conformal-geometry, connections

Let $E$ be  a smooth vector bundle over a manifold $M$, where $\text{rank}(E) > 1,\dim M > 1$. Suppose that $E$ is equipped with a metric $g$ and an affine connection $\nabla$, such that $\nabla_X g=\omega (X) g$ for every $X \in \Gamma(TM)$. (Here $\omega$ is a one form).

**Must $\omega$ be closed?**

Clearly, $\nabla$ is metric-compatible ($\nabla g=0$) iff $\omega=0$. 
Moreover,  $\omega=d\phi$ is exact if and only if $\nabla s=0$ where $s=e^{-\phi}g$, i.e. $\nabla$ is metric w.r.t a positive conformal rescaling of $g$. 
 So, an alternative formulation of the question is the following:

> Suppose that $\nabla g=\omega (\cdot) g$ for some  $\omega \in \Omega^1(M)$. Must $\nabla$ be metric w.r.t a **local** conformal rescalings of $g$?

Differentiating $\nabla g=\omega (\cdot) g$, we get $R(X,Y)g=d\omega(X,Y)g$, so if $\nabla$ is flat then $\omega$ is closed.

---

I required $\text{rank}(E) > 1$, since if the rank is $1$, $\nabla g$ can always be written as $\omega (\cdot) g$ for a suitable $\omega$, so the assumption always holds, but I think that $d\omega=0$ does not always hold. Maybe this can be used to construct a counter example of higher rank by taking a direct sum of line bundles.

Comment: What do you mean by "non-trivial example"? If $(E,\nabla)$ is a vector bundle with a connection and $\xi$ is a flat section ($\nabla \xi = 0$) then $\nabla (f \xi) = df \cdot \xi$. In particular, you can take a triple $(E,\nabla,g)$ when $\nabla$ is metric (so $\nabla g = 0$) and then the triple $(E,\nabla, f\cdot g)$ will give you an example as long as $f > 0$. Is this trivial?

Comment: In other words, given a pair $(E,g)$, you can always take a connection $\nabla$ which is metric with respect to $e^{-\varphi} \cdot g$ and this will give you an example where $\nabla_V (g) = \underbrace{d\varphi(V)}_{\lambda_V} g$. If $\varphi = 0$ then $\nabla$ is metric and you reduce to the even more trivial case $\nabla g = 0$. So a "non-trivial notion" might mean $\nabla g = \omega \cdot g$ where $\omega$ is not an exact/closed one-form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is 'no'. In fact, $\omega$ can chosen to be an arbitrary one-form, at least locally. See [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/324545/46290) for details.